# Form feed does not clear the screen

Tags: c, escaping, ada

I've discovered the Ada programming language recently, but the problem exists in the C programming language as well. The form feed does not work as expected.

Ada Example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
begin
  New_Page;
end Main;
```

Same in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  printf ("\f");
  return 0;
}
```

Both result only in a new line on XTerm as well as Linux console (both with zsh). They should clear instead the screen as an Ctrl-L does.

When called with

```
# ./main | cat -A
```

I get a

```
^L
```

But if I type a

```
# cat -A
```

and type a

```
Ctrl-L
```

I get a

```
^L
```

too.

Does anyone know how to make the form feed work as a Ctrl-L?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2616704 I'm not sure why you expect outputting the ctrl-L character to clear the screen.  Maybe there are some OS's or some terminal emulators or other pieces of software that do this, but it's not standard.  In any case, it is not a language problem with either Ada or C.

Comment: The nomenclature `'\f'` was a mnemonic for 'form feed' and was designed originally to clear the screen (or, more formally, to go to the top of the next page on a printer).  It is not at all unreasonable to expect Control-L to clear the screen.  However, I can also believe that modern terminal emulations don't do it.  If you can find a `termcap` file, you'd find a number of terminal types have `:cl=^L:` as the 'clear screen' command, though none of the ones in my copy were the major manufacturers (Wyse, DEC, etc).

Answer (score 6):

According to [this article](http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/C/How_can_I_clear_the_screen_How_can_I_print_text.html) the proper way to clear the screen is `printf("\033[2J");` (provided your terminal supports ANSI escape sequences and is [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100)-compatible). I can confirm that this works on Linux Mint using GNOME Terminal, and on Windows using xterm and PuTTY.

`^L` clearing the screen doesn't look like a portable convention. For example on HP-UX with the POSIX shell, passing `^L` to the shell doesn't do anything. This seems more like a `bash` occurrence.

Printing `\f` will clear the screen with some terminals but not others. For example logging to a Red Hat host from Windows, I can clear the screen with `printf("\f");` in PuTTY but not in xterm (I get a blank line in the latter case).

Comment: It wouldn't be the shell *per se* but the terminal emulator (or driver if you're on one of the console screens).

Comment: That escape sequence is for 'ANSI' terminals — terminals that adhere to the ANSI standard escape sequences.  Once upon a long time ago, there were many alternative 'green screen' terminals (sometimes, 'orange screen' or another colour was appropriate), each with their own idiosyncratic set of escape sequences.  That led to the production of the `curses` library and first `termcap` and then `terminfo` as ways to describe the variant behaviours.  Then everyone got into terminal emulators instead of real green screen terminals and suddenly it all became easier and the ANSI control codes dominate.

Comment: Yeah, but simply assuming that you're using a vt100-compatible terminal and printing `"\033[2J"` still isn't correct either. I regularly use a system the console of which is not VT100-compatible, on that screen, I'd see the actual `[2J` characters displayed.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: You can always run GNU screen or tmux to "fix" such terminals. :-)

Comment: Yeah... no. I don't think so. Why not just write your program correctly? If you really need to clear the screen, use terminfo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To clarify my problem: The point is that passing an `^L` by keyboard via `Ctrl-L` clears the screen, but an `^L` passed via software doesn't.

Comment: @user2616704 I see, I've noticed that on some terminals you can clear the screen by printing `\f`, yours is an exception to that, my `GNOME Terminal` is too. Can you try a different terminal emulator? For example from Windows with Putty I can clear the screen by printing `\f` but using xterm, I just get a blank line.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to edit @Nobilis' answer to add an Ada version, but I think my edit got lost when the screen was cleared, so here's another try:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
begin
  Put (ASCII.ESC & "[2J");
end Main;
```

In a larger program, you might need to follow it with a "Flush;" call since the above could get buffered by the I/O packages, which probably won't realize this is a special terminal command.  (Same in C, I think: `fflush(stdout);`.)